# Self Signed SSL Certificate 403.7 Error

Tags: ssl, windows-7, iis-7.5, pki

I have been having this issue for about 2 weeks. I have done a lot of research and tried different ways but no joy. I have a development website on my computer (Windows 7 Pro) with sql server 2008 r2 and using IIS 7.5. There is an actual development server running the database and Webserver but because of my location I cannot use the main development site. I issued a self signed Trusted Root Certificate:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=ROOT AUTHORITY" -ss my -sr CurrentUser -a sha1 -sky signature -cy authority -sv ca.pvk ca.cer
```

Then I install that into the trusted root on the local computer. After that I created a certificate for IIS to use.

```
makecert -pe -n "CN=example.website.name.com" -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ic ca.cer -iv ca.pvk -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -sv server.pvk server.cer
```

Then I create the **.pfx** file for IIS

```
pvk2pfx -pvk server.pvk -spc server.cer -pfx server.pfx
```

After I do the above. I import the certificate into IIS and then I bind the website to the SSL certificate **(server.pfx)**

After all that is done, I go on the website https://example.website.name.com and I get 403.7 forbidden.

Can somebody please help me out with this issue?

Comment: Your server's asking the client for a matching cert -- this is sometime known as "mututal SSL". Is that what you expected? If so, have you installed the client cert on your client machine?

Comment: I installed the trusted root cert, the cert for the server and a personal one to access the server. Sorry I should have added that. This is my personal cert: makecert -n "CN=Name" -ic ca.cer -iv ca.pvk -a sha1 -sky exchange -pe -sv name.pvk name.cer  Create the private key cert: pvk2pfx -pvk name.pvk -spc name.cer -pfx name.pfx One more thing to add, this is all on one machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at some of these pitfalls...

Server Issue #1 - The client cert passed in has 1 or more certification paths that do NOT exist on the server. Open the cert go to certification path (tab) and make sure each of the root authorities are in the SERVERS trusted root certificate authorities. Note, you DO NOT need to install the cert on the server just the root authorities public keys under Certificates (Local Computer) \ Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

Server Issues #2 (previously mentioned solution) - In IIS, for the site, make sure the SSL Settings are set to Accept OR Require (never ignore). The benefit of using Require is that the IIS logs will show you are 403 7 error where as Accept will just get your the IsPresent == false but with a 200 http code.

Client Issue #1 - Same as server issue #1, got to trust those authorities!

Client Issue #2 - You have the trusted root authorites but NOT the private key for the cert itself. Make sure you install the pfx (private key) into the cert store not the public key (.cer). You can also see if you have the private key by double clicking the cert in the cert store and on the general tab you should see a message saying as much.

Client Issue #3 - You put the cert in the wrong place. Probably best to place your cert in Certificates (Local Computer) \ Personal \ Certificates, rather than (current user). This will make the cert available to process accounts that are running your code and actually need access to it.

Client Issue #4 - Right mouse click the cert (in the store not a .cer file) --> All Tasks --> Manage Private Keys... and make sure the process account running your code has "Read" permission. A quick test of this (but not recommended for production use) is to add "Everyone" as read to see if this is your issue

Comment: I tried to up vote your response but it says I need a reputation of at least 15. It did work for me. Thanks a lot. PKI can be a pain sometimes.